# listing files in folder showing index.php

Tags: php, dir

I have this code, but it is showing the index.php itself How can I filter *.php files?

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    }
?>

<P>Dir:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Also is there a way to sort them by modification or creation time?

Comment: This code will show _all_ files in the directory.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: to show all files except *.php files

Comment: @cMinor Have a look at my 2nd answer with `ksort` and `krsort`. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another that uses **ksort** or **krsort** functions (tested).
(See comments in code.)

```
<?php
// you can add to the array
$ext_array = array(".htm", ".php", ".asp", ".js"); //list of extensions not required
$dir1 = "."; 
$filecount1 = 0; 
$d1 = dir($dir1);

while ($f1 = $d1->read()) { 
$fext = substr($f1,strrpos($f1,".")); //gets the file extension
if (in_array($fext, $ext_array)) { //check for file extension in list
continue;
}else{
if(($f1!= '.') && ($f1!= '..')) { 
if(!is_dir($f1)) $filecount1++;

$key = filemtime($f1);
$files[$key] = $f1 ;
} 
}
}

// use either ksort or krsort => (reverse order)
//ksort($files);
krsort($files);

foreach ($files as $f1) {
$thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$f1.'">'.$f1.'</a>';
}

?>

<P>Dir:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another exclusion to the part where you ignore '.' and '..' such as:

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !preg_match('/\.php$/i', $file))
```

This will exclude any file with .php at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1) != 'php')
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

(A little something I built)
**This will show you the filename with extension along with file count (tested)**

```
<?php
// you can add to the array
$ext_array = array(".htm", ".php", ".asp", ".js");
//list of extensions not required (above)
$dir1 = "."; 
$filecount1 = 0; 
$d1 = dir($dir1); 

while ($f1 = $d1->read()) { 
$fext = substr($f1,strrpos($f1,".")); //gets the file extension
if (in_array($fext, $ext_array)) { //check for file extension in list
continue;
}else{
if(($f1!= '.') && ($f1!= '..')) { 
if(!is_dir($f1)) $filecount1++;

$thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$f1.'">'.$f1.'</a>';

} 
}
}

// add text and count number below files
echo "Total files in folder: ";
echo "$filecount1";
?>

<P>Dir:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 0):

without overthinking things, this does the job...

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.*") as $f1) {
    if(($f1!= '.') && ($f1!= '..') && ($f1 != '.htaccess') && ($f1!= 'index.php'))
         echo '<a href="'.$f1.'">'.$f1.'</a> </br>';
}

?>
```