# Apache: Allow directory listing but require valid-user to download files

Tags: apache

Is it possible with Apache to enable Indexes for a directory and be able to view every file, but at the same time, password protect only certain file types. When I use `<FilesMatch "\.(type1|type2)">` they become hidden from the  directory listing, but do become password protected. I just need them to be available in the directory listing because... reasons.

Here's what I got that does half the job.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(dat|mca|mcr)$">
        AuthName "Protected Files"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/web/maps/.htpasswd
        require valid-user
</Files>
<Directory /home/web>
        Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexOptions +showForbidden will allow autoindex listings for things that may eventually require authentication (or are forbidden for any other reason!)

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing your own indexer; typically this is just a PHP script in the directory itself (`index.php`) that dynamically retrieves the directory listing. Just like Apache's `mod_autoindex` would, but potentially with nicer looks.

DIY:

- [listing files in folder showing index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555771/listing-files-in-folder-showing-index-php)

Off-the-shelve:

- http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/
- http://pdirl.newroots.de/
- http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script

Comment: Looks like a possible way to go about this. Went covener's answer because it's a simple one line :P

Comment: Rightfully so; covener's way is straightforward and less maintenance-prone.